# Differences in executable behavior between catkin_make and bloom-generate rosdebian, fakeroot debian/rules binary

Tags: ros-noetic, debian

Executable files generated through catkin_make run normally. However, executables from deb packages created with bloom-generate encounter an issue where the main function is called repeatedly after installation.
The root of the problem seems to be my attempt to modify a member variable within a class from a callback function. When I comment out the modifications to this member, the executable no longer repeatedly calls the main function. This issue does not occur when compiling the file with catkin_make.
I am using ROS Noetic on an arm64 architecture. The packaged name is ros-noetic-ac-node_0.0.0-0focal_arm64.deb.
By moving the executable file built with catkin_make to the corresponding folder under /opt/ros/lib/ and rerunning the launch file, the main function does not get called repeatedly and executes normally.

My rules(generated by `bloom-generate`)

```
#!/usr/bin/make -f
# -*- makefile -*-
# Sample debian/rules that uses debhelper.
# This file was originally written by Joey Hess and Craig Small.
# As a special exception, when this file is copied by dh-make into a
# dh-make output file, you may use that output file without restriction.
# This special exception was added by Craig Small in version 0.37 of dh-make.

# Uncomment this to turn on verbose mode.
export DH_VERBOSE=1
# TODO: remove the LDFLAGS override.  It's here to avoid esoteric problems
# of this sort:
#  https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/2977
#  https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3842
export LDFLAGS=
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ros/noetic/lib/pkgconfig
# Explicitly enable -DNDEBUG, see:
#   https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/issues/327
export DEB_CXXFLAGS_MAINT_APPEND=-DNDEBUG
ifneq ($(filter nocheck,$(DEB_BUILD_OPTIONS)),)
    BUILD_TESTING_ARG=-DBUILD_TESTING=OFF -DCATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING=OFF
endif

DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE ?= $(shell dpkg-architecture -qDEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE)

%:
    dh $@ -v --buildsystem=cmake --builddirectory=.obj-$(DEB_HOST_GNU_TYPE)

override_dh_auto_configure:
    # In case we're installing to a non-standard location, look for a setup.sh
    # in the install tree that was dropped by catkin, and source it.  It will
    # set things like CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, and PYTHONPATH.
    if [ -f "/opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh" ]; then . "/opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh"; fi && \
    dh_auto_configure -- \
        -DCATKIN_BUILD_BINARY_PACKAGE="1" \
        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/opt/ros/noetic" \
        -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/ros/noetic" \
        $(BUILD_TESTING_ARG)

override_dh_auto_build:
    # In case we're installing to a non-standard location, look for a setup.sh
    # in the install tree that was dropped by catkin, and source it.  It will
    # set things like CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, and PYTHONPATH.
    if [ -f "/opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh" ]; then . "/opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh"; fi && \
    dh_auto_build

override_dh_auto_test:
    # In case we're installing to a non-standard location, look for a setup.sh
    # in the install tree that was dropped by catkin, and source it.  It will
    # set things like CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, and PYTHONPATH.
    echo -- Running tests. Even if one of them fails the build is not canceled.
    if [ -f "/opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh" ]; then . "/opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh"; fi && \
    dh_auto_test || true

override_dh_shlibdeps:
    # In case we're installing to a non-standard location, look for a setup.sh
    # in the install tree that was dropped by catkin, and source it.  It will
    # set things like CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, and PYTHONPATH.
    if [ -f "/opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh" ]; then . "/opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh"; fi && \
    dh_shlibdeps -l$(CURDIR)/debian/ros-noetic-ac-node//opt/ros/noetic/lib/

override_dh_auto_install:
    # In case we're installing to a non-standard location, look for a setup.sh
    # in the install tree that was dropped by catkin, and source it.  It will
    # set things like CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, and PYTHONPATH.
    if [ -f "/opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh" ]; then . "/opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh"; fi && \
    dh_auto_install
```

I upload my whole workspace on [github](https://github.com/SmileJayjhx/ac_node), error code is ac_driver_manager.cpp, error function is `ACDriverManager::get_manual_auto`, `is_manual_mode` is the variable which will cause main function restart

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the issue was with the compiler optimizations for the arm architecture. By manually modifying the rules to remove the optimization, the problem was resolved. I hope this information can help you. Code below locates at `catkin_ws/debian/rules` which is generated automaticly by `bloom-generate rosdebian`, add three flag     `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug  -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG="-O0 -g" -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG="-O0 -g"` , whole block looks like this:

```
override_dh_auto_configure:
# In case we're installing to a non-standard location, look for a setup.sh
# in the install tree that was dropped by catkin, and source it.  It will
# set things like CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH, PKG_CONFIG_PATH, and PYTHONPATH.
if [ -f "/opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh" ]; then . "/opt/ros/noetic/setup.sh"; fi && \
dh_auto_configure -- \
    -DCATKIN_BUILD_BINARY_PACKAGE="1" \
    -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/opt/ros/noetic" \
    -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/opt/ros/noetic" \
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug \
    -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG="-O0 -g" \
    -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG="-O0 -g" \
    $(BUILD_TESTING_ARG)
```

I was trying to add `-g` to locate the function stack, but problem was solved.